# How to pass va_list between method IMPs? (objective c)

Tags: objective-c, reflection, variadic-functions, swizzling

I'm trying to swizzle a function and call the original implementation with the function args.
the new IMP is of the form:

```
static id WrapperFunction(id self, SEL _cmd, ...) {
     va_list args;
     va_start(args, _cmd);

     originalImp(self, _cmd, args);
     ...
}
```

This is clearly wrong since `args` now contains _cmd while `...` did not.

How can I pass `...` to originalImp?

Answer (score 0):

Gcc has: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Constructing-Calls.html

clang has nothing and you must do assembly to do that (basically if you know the address of originalImp, you just want to "jmp" to it).